# Is it possible to programatically scroll down on a fixed jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, vertical-scrolling

I have a jquery dialog that has a fixed height (which is what i want so please don't response to use height: 'auto')  but I want to see if there is anyway using jquery to programtically scroll the dialog as I am showing errors at the bottom of the dialog and want to make sure the users sees it.

Is this possible to programmatically scroll the window INSIDE a jquery ui dialog to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function:

```
function ScrollTo(id){

      // Scroll
    $('divDialog').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
```

Just pass it the element id and it will scroll to there.

Like this:

```
ScrollTo("div1");
```

Comment: just to clarify, is the id the id of the jquery ui dialog?  This looks like it would be moving the overall browser window (not the dialog)

Comment: where I am passing body you need to pass tha div id selector